# Uniform level density from the sum of i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

I am generating a series of $N$ variables as $X_n=\sum_{i=1}^n{\delta x_i}$ where $n=1,...,N$ and $\delta x_i$ are i.i.d in $[0,\inf]$ with $<\delta x_i>=\int p(\delta x_i)\delta x_i=1$.

I am interested in the density of the generated values $[X_1, X_2,... X_N]$ in the domain $[0,N]$. Histograms of these values suggest a constant density over $[0,N]$. This is in agreement with the intuition that the $n+1$ value is obtain by always adding something that is 1 on average. 
I know the CLT would hold for each $X_n/n$ and here I guess I am getting a constant density within most of the domain of interest from the sum of normal distributions.

Can anyone help me in putting this on a better ground? Can I say something about the behaviour at the boundaries (around zero and around $N$)?

Thanks

Comment: What does it mean that $<\delta x_i >=1$?

Comment: the average of $\delta x_i$ is 1 for all i

Comment: Doesn't the CLT already say a lot?  Assuming (as you implicitly do) that these variables have finite variance, then for large $N$ the distribution near $N$ is approximately Normal with standard deviation proportional to $\sqrt{N}$ and therefore the density near zero will decrease at an exponential rate in $N$. Regardless of the CLT, Chebyshev's Inequality implies that for sufficiently large $N$, the distribution of $X_N$ cannot be anywhere near uniform in $[0,N]$. It's difficult to reconcile this with your intuition.  What else are you looking for?

Comment: whuber thanks, but I am not looking at the distribution of $X_N$ (for that I have CLT). I am looking at the density on the set ${X_1, X_2, ...,X_N}$. This is constant in $[0,$N$]$. I see it numerically, I can understandi it intuitively (I am each time adding something whose average is 1) but I have no idea how to formalize it.

Comment: I'm afraid nothing in your comment is consistent with your question.  Your question quite clearly discusses the distribution of $X_N$ and, as I have pointed out, it is impossible for that to be uniform for large $N$.  What do you mean by "the set $X_1,\ldots, X_N$"?

Comment: To be clear: I generate $N$ numbers $X_1,...,X_N$ as explained in the question. I make an histogram with these numbers. The histogram describes a uniform density. (This is not the distribution of a single $X_n$)

Comment: Please modify your question to clarify this point, because you are not producing a "density" in the conventional sense.  You are producing a histogram of a sequence of (highly) correlated, non-identical variables.  It could help to explain why you might want to look at that histogram, because it seems to hide most of the information in the data rather than reveal anything.

Comment: I changed the text and I hope the point is clearer now. I am producing histograms because I do not know how to show analitically that the generated values have a constant density (I guess in some limit) over $[0,N]$!